# NEST Elasticseach how to match field with many values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to perform a search, where in query I'll provide multiple values which should be matched by one field.

Before I always needed to search by two values, so the code was looking like this:

```
Filter<Document>.Query(q =>
  q.Term(p => p.FieldName, value1) ||
  q.Term(p => p.FieldName, value2));
```

But now I have a list of values. I didn't see any example of that. 
I'm using NEST 1.7.1 
Thanks for some help.

Comment: I'm not trying to answer, but I am trying to clarify the question: If one field must match multiple values, then you can simply search for any one of the values, since they're equal - unless your multiple values are subsets of the one field, in which case it's quite a bit more tricky. Please elaborate?

Comment: @trapsuutjies you're right it was easy solution. I though that if I add many terms to one field it will create AND query and my result will be empty. I was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was really simple, it's a shame I didn't find this earlier.

```
Filter<Document>.Query(q =>
   q.Terms(p=> p.Field, valuesCollection)
);
```